# Best Practice? Making conditional statement strict or following logical flow?

Tags: python, coding-style

So I'm new to coding and I'm going through the Python 100 Days of Code challenge on Udemy and was on the task of creating a leap year calculator. The following is my code vs the instructors code. My thought was have the code executed and logically go through the process of elimination base on what line the condition was on. Both achieved the same outcome but I wanted to know if its solely preference or if her method would be considered best practice. I work in cyber so I want to make sure I get in the habit of doing things the right way from the start to not develop any bad habits/practices.

**My Code**

```
year = int(input("Which year do you want to check? "))

if year % 400 == 0:
    print("Leap Year")
elif year % 100 == 0:
    print("Not leap year")
elif year % 4 == 0:
    print("Leap Year")
else:
    print("Not leap year")
```

**Instructors Code**

```
year = int(input("Which year do you want to check? "))

if year % 4 == 0:
  if year % 100 == 0:
    if year % 400 == 0:
      print("Leap year.")
    else:
      print("Not leap year.")
  else:
    print("Leap year.")
else:
  print("Not leap year.")
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, and actually easier to understand, though it could perhaps still be simplified further. Anyway, this seems opinion-based, and as such unsuitable for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one concrete difference exists between the two ways of coding, so the question is not totally opinion-based (my opinion, of course...)

Suppose you want to check 400 consecutive years in a loop, say 2000 to 2399.

Your first test is executed 400 times, and is true only once; so the second test is executed 399 times, and again it is true only three times; so the third test needs to be executed 396 times. A total of 1.195 `if a % b...` operations.

Instructor code on the contrary executes the first test 400 times, the second test 100 times, and the third test 4 times. A total of 504, i.e. less than half, and hence more than double speed.

Yes, we are talking of a few microseconds, but since it doesn't cost anything I believe the general rule of first applying the tests that solve more cases is a very good habit (this is similar to the classic heuristics used in constraint propagation programming).